# In MSpec, why must all fields under test be static?

Tags: c#, .net, mspec

What makes MSpec require only static fields? For example, the code here causes an error

```
public class When_not_enabled
{
    private static ActionExecutingContext filterContext;

    // On purpose I've made subject non static
    private CompleteOrderGuardFilter subject;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        // Here I get cannot access non static field in static context
        subject = new CompleteOrderGuardFilter(null, false);
        filterContext = new ActionExecutingContext();
    };
}
```

Error:

> cannot access non static field in static context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157580/43846

Comment: two delegates defined         public delegate void Establish();
        public delegate void It(); and a method like         void Method()
        {
            Establish xx = () => a.State = "1";
            It yy = () => a.State = "2";
        } No need that "a" to be static. The question - underneath the surface how is mspec imposing this ?

Answer (score 1):

MSpec does not instantiate the context class but rather calls the Establish/Because/It/Cleanup delegates directly. As such, there is no state (class instance) created and you need all information you want to pass between the delegates to be globally available, e. g. `static`.

Comment: Hello. I understand the need for it. What I am not getting, from implementation point of view, how is the compiler instructed to force the fields to be static ?

Comment: The compiler forces access to static fields itself. This is due to the C# language design.